# how do I give access to netbeans to /var/www/html with

Tags: netbeans

how I give access to /var/www/html netbeans without opening as SU, when I try opening from terminal as SU it won't open

Comment: Many thanks for this response, I'm enjoying Netbeans 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change ownership of html to your user, while group still www-data, with user rw and group r permissions.

```
sudo chown -R youruser:www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /var/www/html
```

After that all user programs will have read-write access to html, and apache will have read access.